# No splash screen on hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate is working fine. A bit slow when resuming from a hibernate but I can bear with it just so that I have all open applications on the desktop as I left it. Then again the "slowness" might be because of the 4GB RAM, although I'm assuming only what is used gets *swapped* and not the entire memory.

Has anyone been able to make Ubuntu show a splash screen or some kind of indicator/progress bar to show while hibernating or while resuming? I remember with SuSE on my HP Compaq Presario notebook it had messages appear during and after. Better than nothing, I guess.

Comment: I have found the same thing with my laptop that has 4gb of ram. It is annoying there is no info/progress bar to give you a clue to what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anything like that. Only "Splash screen" I've ever seen on Ubuntu has been the startup (And occasionally) the shutdown screens.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a replacement for `pm-utils: s2disk/s2ram` displays an hibernate percentage.
It should belong to the `uswsusp` package.